# Integration by parts

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration

### Hi

I want to integrate this integral and ask if my work is correct or not.

$$\int^\infty_0 dx x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x} (a+bx)^{-\alpha}$$

---

I want to integrate it by parts, so I have

$$(a+bx)^{-\alpha} = v$$

$$-b\alpha(a+bx)^{-\alpha-1}dx = dv$$

$$x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x} dx = du$$

$$\Gamma(\alpha) = u$$

---

now the integral becomes

$$\left.\Gamma(\alpha)(a+bx)^{-\alpha}\right|_0^\infty + \int^\infty_0 \Gamma(\alpha) b\alpha(a+bx)^{-\alpha-1}dx = 0$$

---

the problem is in integration by parts. Is it correct to put $$\Gamma(\alpha) = u$$. if it is not correct how can I compute this integral? please help.

Comment: No, it is not correct, since $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is a definite integral of that expression from $0$ to $\infty$, whereas for $u$ you need the indefinite integral of that expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an aside, this is the result from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)

[image]

Comment: I can't see the result.

Comment: @SMH: I don't know why, it works fine for me. This is the imgur link: http://i.imgur.com/2IrTU.gif

Comment: thank you. Now I can see it.